# Indexes on a shared view

Tags: visual-foxpro

I use a view to populate a grid. In order to be able to sort some of the columns I create some indexes for my view when I open the form containing the grid.
It works fine with one user, but when another user opens the app the indexes are not re-created and s/he cannot sort the columns.
Why is that, and what can I do to correct it? TIA

Comment: Editable details of the view, or read-only display?  how are you building the indexes.. Index on .. TO or Index on .. TAG?

Comment: The details are editable and the indexes are created with Index on...TAG

Answer (score 2):

A "view" is just a definition and at runtime it is a "cursor" exclusive to the user. Each user should create the indexes if they want to use it indexed.

Comment: The view is created when the app starts. The indexes are created when the form containing the grid loads. I thought that it made the cursor and the indexes exclusive to each user...

Comment: @Bernard, yes, indexes are exclusive to user via INDEX/TAG.  However, if person "A" adds / edits details,  person "B" view does not KNOW of any such changes and would not necessarily be updated immediately without explicit refreshing.  Might that be what you are having an issue with?  Not seeing changes / additions from another user during simultaneous testing?

Comment: @Bernard, sorry I think I didn't say a different thing. The view's cursor is exclusive to the user and physically (if it is ever created) its table is a temp table on disk. Any indexes created are also exclusive to the user. I would suggest you to use FoxyClasses' Grid classes. It has the sorting and a lot more and you can check the source code.

Comment: @DRapp, theproblem I have is that when the second user tries to sort the data s/he gets a message "The table has no index set". We have not yet reached the point where they would see the other users' changes (which actually should not be too important since these are sales people and they are mostly interested in their clients).

Comment: "The table has no index order set"

Comment: It is hard to understand how you are creating it. Second user is independent of the first. S/he should have created the index(es) and use set order to. If it is about sorting only, then you could do a select, ordering on the column(s) you want without creating any index.

Comment: My "main.prg" creates an instance an "App" class which contains the code to create the view (CREATE SQL VIEW AS...) and in the OpenData method the line USE MyView in 0 NO DATA.
In the Load method of the form that contains the grid:
SELECT vwDdp_all
=REQUERY()

=CURSORSETPROP("Buffering", 1, "vwDdp_all")

INDEX ON nom TAG nom OF ThisView.cdx
INDEX ON montantdev TAG mdev OF ThisView.cdx
INDEX ON dateddp TAG ddp OF ThisView.cdx

=CURSORSETPROP("Buffering", 3, "vwDdp_all")

Again, no problem with the first user, problem with the next one.

Both the EXE and the data are on the network.

Comment: It is a rather large grid, which is why I did not choose the select method.

Comment: Remove those "this ..." and only have the tags. ie: "INDEX ON nom TAG nom"

Comment: BTW, "rather large grid ... " with a view you are doing a select anyway.

Comment: Too many comments... can you just edit your original question and show the code and the context of WHEN the user clicks on whatever to begin the sorting option.  Then we can delete all these comments.  For future, try to keep more content in the original edited post.

Comment: I'll keep your advice in mind for the future. Thank you.
@Cetin Thank you, removing the "OF This..." did the trick. Now, how do I indicate that your answer was the one?